# How do I get column and nested field names in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark df.

`df.printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- bio: string (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- custom_fields: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nested_field1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- first_conversion: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nested_field2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to iterate over column and nested fields in order to get their names (just their names). I should be able to print them and get the following result:

```
bio
city
company
custom_fields
nested_field1
email
first_conversion
nested_field2
number
state
```

I can easily print the first level with:

```
for st in df.schema:
  print(st.name)
```

But how do I check for deeper levels in runtime and recursively?

Answer (score 1):

[`dtypes`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dtypes.html) will give you more details of the schema, you will have to parse it though

```py
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rec: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: float (nullable = true)

df.dtypes
# [('id', 'int'), ('rec', 'array<struct<a:int,b:float>>')]
```